# Verify that local mosquitto MQTT Broker is bridged to test.mosquitto.org

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, ruby-mqtt

I have a local (OSX 11) mosquitto broker (1.4.7) running with the following config:

```
connection test
address test.mosquitto.org
topic in_topic in 0
topic out_topic out 0
try_private false
notifications false
bridge_attempt_unsubscribe true
```

I got the conf settings form here: [bridge local mosquitto to cloud broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255907/bridge-local-mosquitto-to-cloud-broker) (thanks)

I now have 3 terminals.

**A**: subscribed to test.mosquitto.org directly using a ruby script and `ruby-mqtt`.

**B**: subscribed to local broker with `mosquitto_sub -t in_topic`

**C**: publishes using this command: `mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t in_topic -m "hello world1"`

Now, when I do this I get the response in **A** and **B** so that makes me think my bridging connection is working. However, if I drop the `-h test.mosquitto.org` I don't get the message from **A**. So, the message is only going to that broker (test.mosquitto.org) if I include the `-h` option.

On the other hand, if I stop the local mosquitto broker and then run the same command including the `-h` option then the **A** still gets the message and **B** doesn't. **B** actually doesn't even start up since the connection is refused since local broker is not running.

So, my question is, does this configuration actually establish that the brokers are bridging? I am not sure.

**Update:**
As [hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb) pointed out my mistake was that the topic that I was using to publish was not configured to publish out to the other broker. When I updated the conf to `topic in_topic out 0` I succeeded in getting the message directly from the test.mosquitto.org broker without including the `-h test.mosquitto.org` in other words. The message propagated based on the configuration.

The documentation for what I got wrong can be found under the bridging section here: http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get anything in terminal **A** from running the following

```
mosquitto_pub -t in_topic -m "hello world1"
```

Because your bridge is set up to only forward things on `out_topic` from the local broker to the remote (test.mosquitto.org)

```
topic out_topic out 0
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense, and I can confirm, it worked. Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your config if you can:

```
notifications true
```

This will publish to $SYS/broker/connections//state - either a 1 or 0 depending on whether the connection is active. This happens on both the remote and the local broker.