# Mosquitto on Home Assistant: Bridge to remote MQTT broker using CA signed server certificate

Tags: certificate, mqtt, lets-encrypt, mosquitto, home-assistant

How can Mosquitto (The version integrated into Home Assistant) be configured to connect as Bridge to a remote broker using only the "CA signed server certificate" option (like MQTT.fx does) with a Let's encrypt certificate?

E.g. http://mqttfx.jensd.de/ has this option in the connection settings and the connection to the broker works fine:

[image]

The configuration looks like this:

```
connection bridge-01
 log_type all
 require_certificate false
 cleansession true
 try_private true
 bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
 bridge_insecure false
 bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/letsencrypt.crt
 address mycompany.com:8883
 remote_clientdid raspi_test
 remote_username raspi
 remote_password password
 topic # out 0
```

Just as hints:

- Adding the Let's Encrypt root certificate or Let's Encrypt Authority X3 certificate (https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) as `bridge_cafile` fails with a `certificate validation error` or with `socket error on client raspi.local...`.
- Home assistant is run on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Just for completeness reasons)
- Mqtt broker version is Mosquitto 5.1 (Home assistant plugin)
- The connection (clientid, username and password) is ok, works with MQTT.fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bridge_capath /etc/ssl/certs/` instead of `bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/letsencrypt.crt` worked for us.

There are already a lot of pre-installed trusted certificates and the added ones (Let's Encrypt root certificate or Let's Encrypt Authority X3 certificate) in the folder.

A good link to another question explaining this (also it didn't help me), is [bridge local mosquitto to cloud broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255907/bridge-local-mosquitto-to-cloud-broker).

Comment: Do you mean `bridge_capath` not `bridge_cafile`? The problem with the `letsencrypt.crt` is that it probably doesn't contain the full chain.

Comment: @hardillb Sorry for the spelling issue. And yes, that was exactly the problem.